# scodec decode/encode split length field

Tags: scala, scalaz, shapeless, scodec

I am using scodec: https://github.com/scodec/scodec to decode/encode a binary protocol.

I am struggling with a part of the spec where a "length" field is split into two parts by a "moreflag".  The moreflag indicates if the length field needs more space.

```
Example:
Byte 1:  identifier bits 8-7, moreFlag bit 6, length bits 5-0    // first length field filled with 0's if moreFlag is false
Byte 2:  moreFlag bit 8, length bits 7-0  
Byte 3:  otherJunk bits 8-0
```

My problem is I want to encode/decode both of these length fields into a single case class field:

```
case class Header(totalLength: Int, otherJunk: Int)
```

I have tried a few different things, but nothing has worked out so far:

```
implicit val headerCodec: Codec[Header] = (
  ("identifier" | uint2) :~>:
  ("moreFlag" | bool).compact >>:~ { meta => 
    if (meta.last) {
      // more flag enabled, combine lengths somehow
      ("first length part" | uint(5)) :: ("moreFlag2DontCare" | uint(1) :~>: ("second length part - how to combine?" | uint(7)) :: ("otherJunk" | uint8) 
    }
    else {
      ("first length part always 0s" | constant(bin"00000")) :: ("moreFlag2DontCare" | uint(1) :~>: ("fullLength" | uint(7)) :: ("otherJunk" | uint8)
    }
  }
).as[Header]
```

Am I on the right track here?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to accomplish this is to use the predefined combinators to define the structure of the binary format -- not the combination logic. Then put the combination logic inside a function passed to `xmap`.

```
import scodec._
import bits._
import codecs._
import shapeless._

case class Header(totalLength: Int, otherJunk: Int)

object Header {
  implicit val codec: Codec[Header] = {
    type Struct = Int :: Boolean :: BitVector :: Boolean :: BitVector :: Int :: HNil
    val struct: Codec[Struct] = ("identifier" | uint2) :: ("moreFlag" | bool) :: ("upper length bits" | codecs.bits(5)) :: ("moreFlag2" | bool) :: ("lower length bits" | codecs.bits(7)) :: ("other junk" | uint8)
    def to(header: Header): Struct = {
      val lengthBits = uint(12).encodeValid(header.totalLength)
      val more = !(lengthBits startsWith bin"00000")
      0 :: more :: lengthBits.take(5) :: false :: lengthBits.drop(5) :: header.otherJunk :: HNil
    }
    def from(struct: Struct): Header = struct match {
      case id :: moreFlag :: upperLengthBits :: moreFlag2 :: lowerLengthBits :: otherJunk :: HNil =>
        val length =
          if (moreFlag) uint(12).decodeValidValue(upperLengthBits ++ lowerLengthBits)
          else uint(7).decodeValidValue(lowerLengthBits)
        Header(length, otherJunk)
    }
    struct.xmap[Header](from, to)
  }
}
```

Note that the upper and lower length bits are encoded as `bits(5)` and `bits(7)` and then manually combined in the `from` function and decoded. The decoding is safe, despite using the unsafe `decodeValidValue`, because the `uint(12)` codec is total on 12-bit inputs -- it is impossible for it to return a left.

However, the `to` function uses `encodeValid`, which is clearly unsafe -- e.g., `Int.MaxValue` will cause an exception. We can fix this with a slightly more complicated version, where the `to` function returns an `Err \/ Struct`, and we call `widen` instead of `xmap`:

```
object Header {
  implicit val codec: Codec[Header] = {
    type Struct = Int :: Boolean :: BitVector :: Boolean :: BitVector :: Int :: HNil
    val struct: Codec[Struct] = ("identifier" | uint2) :: ("moreFlag" | bool) :: ("upper length bits" | codecs.bits(5)) :: ("moreFlag2" | bool) :: ("lower length bits" | codecs.bits(7)) :: ("other junk" | uint8)
    def to(header: Header): Err \/ Struct = {
      uint(12).encode(header.totalLength) map { lengthBits =>
        val more = !(lengthBits startsWith bin"00000")
        0 :: more :: lengthBits.take(5) :: false :: lengthBits.drop(5) :: header.otherJunk :: HNil
      }
    }
    def from(struct: Struct): Header = struct match {
      case id :: moreFlag :: upperLengthBits :: moreFlag2 :: lowerLengthBits :: otherJunk :: HNil =>
        val length =
          if (moreFlag) uint(12).decodeValidValue(upperLengthBits ++ lowerLengthBits)
          else uint(7).decodeValidValue(lowerLengthBits)
        Header(length, otherJunk)
    }
    struct.widen[Header](from, to)
  }
}
```

Comment: This is what I wanted - thanks for your great library!